# Alter default parameters of a function in a decorator in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, wrapper, decorator

I have a decorator to alter string arguments passed to functions:

```
def decorator(fn):
    def wrapper(*args):
        replacements = list()
        for arg in args:
            new_item = arg + "!!!"
            replacements.append(new_item)
        args = tuple(replacements)
        print fn(*args)
    return wrapper
```

I have a very simple function with a default parameter that I would like to pass to `decorator`:

```
def f1(arg1="Hello world"):
     return arg1
```

To my surprise

```
decorator(f1)() # using the default argument
```

returned an undecorated `Hello world`.

I did some research, and found out that [default arguments are only evaluated at function creation time](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm). I also learned that parameters with a default value are stored in the `.func_defaults` property. With this information I altered my decorator to get it working the way I want by changing the line

```
for arg in args:
```

to

```
for arg in args + fn.func_defaults:
```

### Question

Why isn't the default parameter value of function `f1` passed to the `*args` in the wrapper and altered as expected?

Comment: So... you've answered your own question?

Comment: Really? If so, could you explain it to me also, because I'm still struggling with it. You're probably referring to the default arguments that are evaluated at function creation time. How does that influence the passing of the argument to the wrapper?

Comment: `args` in the wrapper only contains the arguments passed in by the caller, which in your case is none. Therefore the default argument is used, which is stored in `fn.func_defaults`. Remember the decorator is "outside" the decorated function.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `return fn(*args)` instead of `print fn(*args)`?

Comment: @tobias_k is there any difference in this case?

Comment: @Neftas Not in this example, but this could cause a huge headache if you tried to use this decorator in practice.